# How can I look for equality with tolerance between 2 cells who have lists of float numbers in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, range, equality

could someone please help me?

I have an array with three columns *a, b ,c* and say *100 rows*.

Each cell contains a list of floats as the following:

```
[[102.264], [102.376], [102.488], [102.6], [10...  
[[104.718], [104.725], [104.732], [105.771]]
```

What I would like to do is for each row, compare a with b and set in c the floats that have equality(values in b = values in a) and the floats that have an approximative match (values in b are in a tolerance of say 0,1 with values in a).

Ive spent endless hours online and trying to figure out something that works but havent succeeded.

I found the following methods maybe someone with advanced skills could help:

- pandas.merge_asof
- np.isclose

When I try one of the methods above I get error messages. I'm really quite a noob and therefore don't know what I must do. Must I initially change the type of columns a, b ,c ? Must I expand each list into a pandas array? I really don't know... Please help

My expected result is to have columns c per row having the floats that are:

- values of b = values of a
- values of b = values of a in a tolerance of 0,01

Could someone please help? Im really begging and I'm will to PayPal..

Thank you for your time in reading this post and in advance for your help!

Example of result array:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Edp.png)

Comment: Can we see some code please?

Comment: You should include a **minimal** example of the data: a few rows where *`each cell`* contains a list of 3-4 items.  `I have an array...` - what kind of array? is it a Pandas DataFrame? A Numpy array? A lists of lists?

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick replies. As I said im quite a noob I think its a Numpy Array. Heres an example of the array without c filled:

                                                a                                             b        c
0                                         NaN                                                NaN      NaN
1  [104.264], [104.376], [104.488], [104.6],  [10 …  [[106.718],  [106.725], [106.732], [106.771], [...    NaN
2                                                NaN  [[104.931], [104.945], [104.959], [104.973], [...    NaN

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Is this a `pandas` dataframe?  Or just a list (of lists etc), or a numpy array (if so what `shape` and `dtype`?  `isclose` compares values of numpy array - but it has to be numeric, not object dtype.  If can handle floats like `nan` and `inf`.  `allclose` applies `isclose` to whole arrays.

Comment: Its a pandas data frame, a and b are object containing list of floats.

Comment: `pandas` with lists in cells gets messy, especially if the lists vary in size.

Comment: They vary in size and a and b sizes aren't the same... For example: row 1 and column 'a' has a list 150 floats and for row 1 and column 'b' has a list of 90 floats...

Comment: Does it look something like this?: `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[[101.0],[102.0]],[[101.0],[102.0]]], 'b':[[[101.0],[102.0]],[[101.0],[102.0]]]})`

Comment: Hey wwii, yes it looks like this but in my case each list can be different size..

Comment: I just converted the array to a Numpy Array. By using allclose it will return true for values in a tolerance. But how can I pick each true value from the list and set the true value in c?

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you just run a and b through the code below and check whether it returns true or false?

```
def check_if_close(a, b):
    if (abs(b-a) < 0.1):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(check_if_close(9.1, 9.15)) #true
print(check_if_close(8.1, 9.15)) #false
print(check_if_close(7.06, 8.0)) #false
print(check_if_close(7.06, 7.1)) #true
```

See if that meets your needs.

Comment: I imagine that the OP is having a problem extracting the values from the data structure for comparison, not comparing them after they have been extracted.

Comment: Thanks Mathew but this doesn't really solve my problem since im comparing lists in a cell of a pandas array. Want to compare b with a and extract into c all values of a that are equal to b or in a range of 0,1